# Create SAPUI5 application programmatically?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

If it is possible at all, how do I create a new SAPUI5 application on my SAP HANA Cloud Platform account from an existing and running SAPUI5 HTML5 application?

UPDATE:

I don't want to enter the cockpit, I want to create a new app on my account using only Javascript/SAPUI5/whatever. I need that process to be automated.

Comment: you have Web IDE access?

Comment: Give me moment I'll get back..

Comment: You can develop **XSJS** application and host in SAP HANA to create oData service and consume those services in **SAPUI5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was told by SAP, as of now, there is no possibility to do what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy an HTML5 application in the following way:

1. In the cockpit, create a new application.
2. Clone the Git repositories of both the existing and new application, and copy the repository content into the new application.
3. Commit the content in the new application's repository and push the commit.
4. In the cockpit, create a version for the new commit in the new application, and activate that version.

Comment: That's the trick - I want to know if I can press a button in the running on my account HTML5 application and a new application will be created on my account. All that without entering the cockpit, just pure javascript/SAPUI5/whatever.

Comment: Well how to do this in an automated way is a different question. Changing the scope of a question is frowned upon at stackoverflow, but you can certainly ask a new question stating that you look for an automated solution.

Comment: But that's exactly what I asked - to create a new app from existing and running app. But your comment made me think I wasn't clear enough. I'll update the question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: You say "programmatically" in the title - but I didn't read the title again. Unfortunately then I don't have a good answer for you. There is currently no API for creating HTML5 applications.